# How take html structure beetween tags

Tags: jquery

Site have this kind of structure

```
<div class="main">
hello world<br />
againg hello world<br />
   <h3>some text</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>again text</li>
      <li>again text</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now, i want take text with all br tags or with same html structure beetween class main and h3.
i used to .prevUntil() but can't do anything

Comment: Do you have option of changing the html structure? If so, you should consider that instead and wrap the contents you want in a tag.

Comment: i'm grabbing text from another site, that's why there's no way to change the structure

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var html = $('#main').clone().find('>*').remove().html();
```

This creates a clone of your #main div and removes all child elements, leaving only the text.

Though it would be better to wrap that text in another element like a `p`.

Comment: in this case .html() not working and this code takes h3 and ul text.
i did like this
`$(".main").clone().find("h3,ul").remove();`
`var html = $(".main").text();`